# What is the proper name for these cheating F#m & G#m chords?

Tags: guitar, chords

```
%2/x.4/3.4/4.2/1.0/0.0/0
```

It's basically a standard F#m barre, but without the barre. The low E string is generally not played. You can also move it two frets up to get a G#m shape, which still works but is not quite as nice - I can use this F#m in virtually any song but the G#m sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't depending on the song.

How would these be properly named?

Comment: The jTab is fine. SO has a bug where it doesn't process the jTab after you submit. Hit "reload" and it shows up.

Answer (score 3):

A form of F♯m11. As there's F♯, C♯, A, the triad of F♯m, with a ♭7 (E) and a 4 (B). 11ths sometimes have the 9th missing, as in this case, but must have a 7th of some sort. Can't be called a sus 4, as the 3 is still there. Often guitar needs to omit something, as it's not easily available to finger/fret. The ‘G♯m’ is an E maj7, and sounds better voiced *with* the bottom E, and *without* the top E.

To find the names of chords, establish a basic triad—usually maj. or min., then count up from the root to any extra notes. These give the number to attach to the chord name.

Comment: I would write the first chord as "F#m7 Add 11"